# How to ssh with Arrays in Expect/Tcl?

Tags: arrays, ssh, tcl, expect

I can successfully spawn a ssh session perform some scp's and execute a bash script in Excpet/Tcl. However, when I try to ssh into muiltiple systems via a for loop and arrays, I get an `ssh: Could not resolve hostname $SOME_HOST: Temporary failure in name resolution` error.

I would really like to be able to make this nice by using arrays, but for whatever reason, Expect/Tcl has issues when trying to use arrays with ssh.

```
#arrays
array set userArray {
    0 $A_USERNAME
    1 $A_USERNAME
    2 $A_USERNAME
    3 $B_USERNAME
    4 $B_USERNAME
    5 $A_USERNAME
    6 $A_USERNAME
    7 $A_USERNAME
    8 $A_USERNAME
    9 $A_USERNAME
    10 $B_USERNAME
    #11 $B_USERNAME
}

array set hostArray {
    0 $A_HOST
    1 $B_HOST
    2 $C_HOST
    3 $D_HOST
    4 $E_HOST
    5 $F_HOST
    6 $H_HOST
    7 $I_HOST
    8 $J_HOST
    9 $K_HOST
    10 $L_HOST
    #11 $M_HOST
}

array set sshPasswordArray {
    0 "placeholder0"
    1 "placeholder1"
    2 "placeholder2"
    3 "placeholder3"
    4 "placeholder4"
    5 "placeholder5"
    6 "placeholder6"
    7 "placeholder7"
    8 "placeholder8"
    9 "placeholder9"
    10 "placeholder10"
    #11 "placeholder11"
}


#expect "$ " { send -- "cd /tmp/\r" }



#This loop will step through every system on a system sshing and then running $LINUX_HARDWARE_COLLECTION_FILE on said system. 
for { set index 0 } { $index < $NUM_SYSTEMS_IN_A_SYSTEM } { incr index } {
    puts "In loop: $index"
    spawn ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -l $userArray($index) $hostArray($index)
    expect "*?assword:" 
    send "$sshPasswordArray($index)\r"
    #do some stuff here including executing $LINUX_HARDWARE_COLLECTION_FILE...
}
```

Does anyone know how one can successfully do this? The issue seems to be that Excpet/Tcl does not want to read the values of my arrays. For the above code assume `A_USERNAME`, `B_USERNAME`, the various hosts, and passwords are valid strings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `array set` command, when used like that, does not substitute the variables in those definitions. For example, `hostArray(0)` is set to the literal characters `$A_HOST`. The easy way to fix this is to use the `subst` command to post-process the values before use.

```
for { set index 0 } { $index < $NUM_SYSTEMS_IN_A_SYSTEM } { incr index } {
    puts "In loop: $index"
    spawn ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -l \
            [subst $userArray($index)] [subst $hostArray($index)]
    expect "*?assword:" 
    send "$sshPasswordArray($index)"
    #do some stuff here including executing $LINUX_HARDWARE_COLLECTION_FILE...
}
```

Also, remember to put a `\r` at the end of the `send` of the password (to simulate the pressing of the <kbd>Return</kbd> key) and don't forget to `close` the spawned subprocess at the end of the loop. (It's not usually critical for 10 items, but there's a fairly small number of virtual terminals that you can have open at once and that includes all the other users of them on your machine; it's good practice to keep the number open at once as small as possible.)

---

You could also use it at the point of the `array set` but that can come unstuck if you have variables with spaces in so I don't really recommend it:

```
array set userArray [subst {
    0 $A_USERNAME
    1 $A_USERNAME
    ... ...
}]
```

NB: `array set` doesn't support a comment format at all. You've made entries with the key `#11` in your example…

Comment: Thank you so much! That did the trick! Missing `\r` on my `send` was unintentional, and thanks for catching that too!

Answer (score 0):

Arrays in Tcl are associative arrays that map an arbitrary string to a string.
Lists in Tcl are numerically indexed arrays.

You may as well do this:

```
set hostArray [list $A_HOST     $B_HOST     $C_HOST     $D_HOST     $E_HOST     $F_HOST     $H_HOST     $I_HOST     $J_HOST     $K_HOST     $L_HOST     $M_HOST]
set userArray [list $A_USERNAME $A_USERNAME $A_USERNAME $B_USERNAME $B_USERNAME $A_USERNAME $A_USERNAME $A_USERNAME $A_USERNAME $A_USERNAME $B_USERNAME $B_USERNAME]
set sshPasswordArray {
    "placeholder0"
    "placeholder1"
    "placeholder2"
    "placeholder3"
    "placeholder4"
    "placeholder5"
    "placeholder6"
    "placeholder7"
    "placeholder8"
    "placeholder9"
    "placeholder10"
    "placeholder11"
}
```

Then, iterate

```
for { set index 0 } { $index < [llength $userArray] } { incr index } {
    puts "In loop: $index"
    spawn ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -l [lindex $userArray $index] [lindex $hostArray $index]
    expect "*?assword:" 
    send "[lindex $sshPasswordArray $index]\r"
    #do some stuff here including executing $LINUX_HARDWARE_COLLECTION_FILE...
}
```

or, much more readable with foreach

```
foreach  user $userArray  host $hostArray  sshPassword $sshPasswordArray {
    spawn ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -l $user $host
    expect "*?assword:" 
    send "$sshPassword\r"
    #do some stuff here including executing $LINUX_HARDWARE_COLLECTION_FILE...
}
```